# List of all databases on firebird

Tags: firebird

We have a 3rd party creating databases on a firebird server and we would like our software to automatically detect/find these additional databases when it starts up.

Is is possible to connect to the server and retrieve a list of available databases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible.

Why you need this ?

Comment: Thanks. Really it's just for convenience, if it can't be done, so be it.

Comment: I'm not sure, but if it was possible, in any Database Server, that could be a great flaw in security. No?

Comment: @EMBarbosa : I think MySQL allow this.

Comment: In some purposes this functionality is needed. For example probing the databases in runtime when user needs to do some configuration which I'm currently working on. In MSSQL, Mysql and others it's possible. To provide security, of course user credentials should be provided.